# Maven and POI how to understand better the file Excel in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache, maven, apache-poi

I'm trying to move the first steps in Apache POI following this link:
[here](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook)

I've found very difficult to understand how must put the code and the packages to import in Eclipse with Maven. If I try to copy the code [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/examples/HSSFReadWrite.java) I obtain a sequence of errors caused by, for exemple, import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell; Deleting that, I get in any case problem with the code.

Do you know any linear guide to reach the same purpose? I need, at the end, to be able to getting cell contents, obviously in a excel file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is most probably because the supporting POI jars aren't in your classpath. Lookup how to add JARs to the classpath (it can vary slightly depending on whether your project is standalone, or a web based project, etc.). If you are using Maven for your project, check what entries to make in the pom.xml for POI libraries.

Comment: Please add your pom.xml in the description. This would help us better understand the problem. Basically, you will have to add the `apache poi` jar as a dependency in your pom.xml file.

Comment: <artifactId>ExcelPass</artifactId><packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ExcelPass</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version><scope>test</scope></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId><artifactId>poi</artifactId><version>3.14</version>
</dependency></dependencies>
  <properties><maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
</project>

Comment: Are you getting any error in your pom.xml file ? and are you using maven in eclipse directly using plug-in ?

Answer (score 3):

To Use apache POI you need to have relevant dependencies on your project POM file. If you are going to read excel format XLS (1997-2003) then you need to have following dependency

```
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

<artifactId>poi</artifactId>

<version>3.15</version>
```

If you are going to read excel format XLSX(Workbook) then you may need to have following two dependencies

```
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>

<version>3.15</version>
```

```
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

<artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>

<version>3.15</version>
```

Then you can read excel files according to the [following  post](http://nirmalbalasooriya.blogspot.sg/2016/11/read-excel-file-from-apache-poi-xls-or.html).

Comment: Thank you for you help, I grasp that I haven't loaded the Jar file, and now the errors are fixed.
Now I need a clear guide to understand better everything.